Is this a correct implementation of atomic reference counting in C?
Giving the following constraints, is the optimization in this code correct?

before an object is transfered to another thread, its reference count is incremented and is_shared is set to true.
everytime an object reaches a reference count of 1, is_shared is set to false.
Header_is_unique is 100% thread safe.

The idea behind the optimization is to try reduce the amount of atomic operations.
Is this a fool's errand? Is this kind of optimization impossible to do in a thread safe manner without using more atomic values and/or mutexes, thus invalidating the idea of the optimization itself?
I only want to target the GCC and Clang compiler.
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct Header {
    uint8_t is_shared;
    uint64_t reference_count;
} Header;

void
Header_acquire(
    Header * const self
) {
    if (!self->is_shared) {
        ++self->reference_count;
    } else {
        __atomic_fetch_add(&self->reference_count, 1, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    }
}

uint8_t
Header_release(
    Header * const self
) {
    if (!self->is_shared) {
        return !--self->reference_count;
    }

    uint64_t const reference_count =
        __atomic_fetch_sub(&self->reference_count, 1, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);

    if (reference_count == 2) {
        __atomic_thread_fence(__ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
        self->is_shared = 0;
    }

    return reference_count == 1;
}

uint8_t
Header_is_unique(
    Header const * const self
) {
    return !self->is_shared && self->reference_count == 1;
}


Note: cross-posted on SE Code Review.

Even if you only care about gcc/clang, you might as well use C11 <stdatomic.h> operations rather than the non-portable __atomic builtins.  They're equally efficient, but better documented, and more likely to be understood by others reading your code.

@NateEldredge: Indeed.  And making your variables _Atomic means the default is atomic loads and stores with seq_cst, unlike here with plain variables where the default for things like reference_count == 2 is a non-atomic access (and data-race UB) if you forget to use __atomic_load_n(&reference_count, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE).  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fatomic_005fload_005fn)

@NateEldredge: One thing you can't do with C11 stdatomic.h is an equivalent of C++20 atomic_ref, to make some accesses to a variable atomic and some plain, to optimize non-shared accesses.  And actually the OP seems to be trying to do that, branching on is_shared and/or reference_count to non-atomically decrement the ref count (not even separate atomic load / separate atomic store, but totally non-atomic so it could perhaps be kept in a register across multiple calls that all have non-atomic accesses to is_shared letting the compiler assume it's unchanged.)

Please note that cross-posting is generally frowned upon.

Unfortunately, your implementation has a race condition.
Header_release will set is_shared to 0 when reference_count is decremented [to the correct value].
But, the change to is_shared is not atomic. Hence, the race.
Also, Header_acquire does not set is_shared to 1 when reference_count is incremented sufficiently. Thus, it is not consistent with the usage in Header_release
So, to alleviate the race, access to is_shared would have to always be atomic.
This occurs because is_shared is changed dynamically.
As you mentioned, this is probably not what you'd want (i.e. if trying to eliminate extra atomic operations).

When I've used similar structs, I've always set the type of the struct as either shared or private during initialization only.
This isn't a great hardship because, with correct/careful design, we always know whether a given struct instance is shared or not. Or, may become shared (which means that it is shared).
Here is how I would refactor the code. It eliminates non-atomic access to is_shared. But, it may have other errors, possibly in Header_unique (which I'm having some trouble understanding the utility of)
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

typedef struct Header {
    uint8_t is_shared;
    uint8_t is_alloc;
    uint64_t reference_count;
} Header;

#define HDR_VALUES(_share,_alloc) \
    { .is_shared = _share, .is_alloc = _alloc }

#define HDR_SHARED(_sym) \
    Header _sym = HDR_VALUES(1,0)

#define HDR_PRIVATE(_sym) \
    Header _sym = HDR_VALUES(0,0)

HDR_SHARED(my_shared_header);
HDR_PRIVATE(my_private_header);

Header *
Header_new(Header *self,uint8_t is_shared)
{

    if (self == NULL) {
        self = malloc(sizeof(*self));
        self->is_alloc = 1;
    }
    else
        self->is_alloc = 0;

    self->is_shared = is_shared;

    self->reference_count = 0;

    return self;
}

void
Header_acquire(Header * const self)
{
    if (!self->is_shared) {
        ++self->reference_count;
    }
    else {
        atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&self->reference_count, 1, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    }
}

uint8_t
Header_release(Header * const self)
{
    if (!self->is_shared) {
        return !--self->reference_count;
    }

    uint64_t const reference_count =
        atomic_fetch_sub_explicit(&self->reference_count, 1, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);

#if 0
    if (reference_count == 2) {
        atomic_thread_fence(__ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
        self->is_shared = 0;
    }
#endif

    return reference_count == 1;
}

uint8_t
Header_is_unique(Header const *const self)
{
#if 0
    return !self->is_shared && self->reference_count == 1;
#else
    uint8_t ret;
    if (self->is_shared)
        ret = 0;
    else
        ret = self->reference_count == 1;
    return ret;
#endif
}


It eliminates non-atomic access to is_shared - You missed a few reads.  is_shared still _Atomic, so if (self->is_shared) is a non-atomic access and can be hoisted out of loops and assumed because it would be UB for another thread to write it without synchronization.  But that's actually fine if it never changes after a struct is published to other threads, as you suggested would be better design.  Concurrent read-only access is fully safe.  If you wanted to use atomic reads, __atomic_load_n( &self->is_shared, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE ) or whatever order is appropriate.

But yes, looks reasonable and maintains the OP's branching to use atomic vs. fully non-atomic RMWs of reference_count.  (vs. store( 1+load(&refcount), acquire ).  Shouldn't Header_acquire use __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE?  I haven't really thought through the design, but it has acquire in the function name and nothing else will sync-with the release RMWs in Header_release.

Header is meant to be used as an header in C style inheritance in COW objects. The purpose of Header_is_unique is to check if the object is in single threaded mode and if it has just one reference to it, and thus if it is safe to mutate. Since most objects live and die on the same thread and only occasionally may cross to another thread, I was trying to optimise for that use case.

I thought that setting is_shared on release was safe because now there’s effectively only one reference and thus the object is now owned by a single thread. The idea was to manually set is_shared to 1 every time the object crossed to other threads. If all the data race is causing is false positives, then all that would cost me would be an additional copy of the object as a form to maintain copy on write consistency. I’m open to a different design.

Wait a minute, this tries to use atomic_fetch_sub_explicit() on a plain uint64_t.  It only works on an object that's _Atomic (unlike the GNU C __atomic builtins).

Worse, on 32-bit x86 for example, the reference_count struct member won't be sufficiently aligned; it'll start at 4 bytes into the struct, because alignof(unsigned long long) is only 4 in i386 SysV.  So you can have a cache-line-split locked op, incredibly slow.  Or on some other 32-bit ISAs, maybe non-atomic or faulting.  Just use unsigned long or uintptr_t and make it alignas(_Atomic uintptr_t) (@JoãoPires).  You don't need to waste space on 64-bit ref counts.

@PeterCordes, uint64_t is fine for me as I have no intention on supporting a 32bits executable.

@JoãoPires but why would you want a 16-byte struct instead of 8?  Wasting cache footprint is generally worse even on 64-bit machines.  You're not going to have 2^32 references to an object.  And if it's not even going to work correctly on 32-bit machines, you should document that in code you're publishing for other people to use (by posting it on Stack Overflow.)

this code is wrong by design. look at Header_release. whah is mean condition ?
if (reference_count == 2) {

this mean that now only single thread have reference to self, but this is ANOTHER thread, not current. really at this point curent thread have no more  reference to Header and must not access it at all.
self->is_shared = 0;

is wrong here - we have no right to do this from the current thread. because another thread, wjo hold last reference, is owber of struct now. it can destroy this struct at all (in this case we modify not valid memory), or pass it to another thread ( so set self->is_shared = TRUE; )
for reproduce error it test - we need set pause between if (reference_count == 2) and self->is_shared = 0; and let another thread do something with self at this time. in windows we can use MessageBoxW for such.
we can reproduce error with such code:
void HFree(Header * self)
{
    if (Header_release(self))
    {
        delete self;
    }
}

uint32_t __stdcall thread_proc(Header * self)
{
    wchar_t sz[16];
    swprintf_s(sz, _countof(sz), L"[%x]", GetCurrentThreadId());
    MessageBoxW(0, sz, L"thread_proc", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    HFree(self);
    return 0;
}

void StartThread(Header * self)
{
    Header_acquire(self);
    self->is_shared = TRUE;

    // winapi, but does not change the essence
    if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)thread_proc, self, 0, 0))
    {
        NtClose(hThread);
    }
    else
    {
        HFree(self);
    }
}

void demo()
{
    if (Header* self = new Header)// c++, but does not change the essence
    {
        self->reference_count = 1;
        self->is_shared = FALSE;

        int n = 2;
        do 
        {
            MessageBoxW(0, L"StartThread", L"demo", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            StartThread(self);
        } while (--n);

        MessageBoxW(0, L"1", L"demo", MB_ICONINFORMATION);

        HFree(self);
        MessageBoxW(0, L"exit", L"demo", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
}

by manipulate wit messagebox we can construct use after free or self->is_shared == 0 with 2+ threads have reference to Header
correct implementation with pure referene count:
typedef struct Header {
    long reference_count;
} Header;

void Header_acquire(Header *self) 
{
    __atomic_fetch_add(&self->reference_count, 1, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
}

void Header_release( Header * self) 
{
    if (1 == __atomic_fetch_sub(&self->reference_count, 1, __ATOMIC_RELEASE)) {
        delete self;// free memory
    }
}

uint32_t __stdcall thread_proc(Header * self)
{
    wchar_t sz[16];
    swprintf_s(sz, _countof(sz), L"[%x]", GetCurrentThreadId());
    MessageBoxW(0, sz, L"thread_proc", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    Header_release(self);
    return 0;
}

void StartThread(Header * self)
{
    Header_acquire(self);

    if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)thread_proc, self, 0, 0))
    {
        NtClose(hThread);
    }
    else
    {
        Header_release(self);
    }
}

void demo()
{
    if (Header* self = new Header)// c++, but does not change the essence
    {
        self->reference_count = 1;

        int n = 2;
        do 
        {
            StartThread(self);
        } while (--n);

        MessageBoxW(0, L"1", L"demo", MB_ICONINFORMATION);

        Header_release(self);
        MessageBoxW(0, L"exit", L"demo", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
}

note that uint32_t enouth for reference_count, not need use uint64_t.
we can use delete self; or free(free); or in more general - access self after if (1 == __atomic_fetch_sub(&self->reference_count, 1, __ATOMIC_RELEASE)) because this condidion mean - no other threads have  pointers to the object - so we single and exclusive owner of object in this point and can do anything with it. free it memory. compare this to only single thread have reference to self, but this is ANOTHER thread, not current - so we not owner here, but another thread
